# Handle two key event in as 2 ctrl + left click

Tags: events, actionscript-2, flashdevelop

I want to catch both the single left click and the ctrl + left click in as2.
I am using FlashDevelop and coded this (it works):

```
_mc._back.onRelease = function() :Void
{
    var args:Array = new Array();
    args.push((_root._xmouse - this._parent._posMiniMapX) * this._parent._ratio);
    args.push((_root._ymouse - this._parent._posMiniMapY) * this._parent._ratio + this._parent._bpa / this._parent._ratio);
    fscommand("MoveCameraMiniMap", args);
}
```

How can I handle the both event?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the approach that I've usually taken is to listen to keyboard events on the CTRL key then evaluate that onRelease to determine the correct action.

But you could simply check the key.isDown status within the onRelease

```
_mc._back.onRelease = function() :Void {
 if(Key.isDown(17)) {
  // do CTRL + mouse action
 } else {
  // do standard action
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
It works but I had to change the variable from "key" to "Key" and 32 to 17. ^^

Comment: good to hear and I've updated the answer accordingly (my bad for hand-typing!)